# Comparar dos vectores elemento a elemento

Tags: python, lista

Tengo dos listas en Python:

```
a = [1, 5, 5]
b = [2, 10, 8]
```

Si `1 < 2` y `5 < 10` y `5 < 8`, es decir si cada elemento de la lista `a` es menor que su correspondiente elemento de lista `b`, entonces la variable `c` valdrá `1`; si no valdrá `0`.

He intentado hacerlo utilizando `numpy.where` pero luego no encuentro una función que diga si el vector resultante está vacío o no (un equivalente a `isempty` de matlab)

Esto es lo que he intentado de momento:

```
a = [10, 10, 10]
b = [1, 1, 1] 
a = np.asarray(a)
b = np.asarray(b)

if np.where(abs(a) / 5 < abs(b)): residual_check = 1 
else: residual_check = 0 

print(residual_check)
```

**¿Cómo lo podría hacer?**

Comment: Buenas Luca. Una vez tengas el array `c = [ 1 1 1 ]` , para que quieres saber si el vector está vacío?

Comment: lo que quiero es comparar las dos listas si hay un elemento de la lista a que es mayor que el elemento en su misma posicion en la lista b entoces la variable c tiene que vale 1

Comment: Si, eso lo entiendo , pero la parte de *"luego no encuentro una función que diga si el vector resultate esta vacio o no ( un equivalente a isempty de matlab)"*? Igualmente has de mostrar lo que has intentado para crear el array `C`

Comment: a=[10,10,10]
b=[1,1,1]
a=np.asarray(a)
b=np.asarray(b)

np.where(abs(a)/5 < abs(b))
#len(np.where(abs(a)/5 < abs(b)))

if np.where(abs(a)/5 < abs(b)):
    residual_check=1
else:
    residual_check=0
print(residual_check)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si quieres hacer con python "puro" sin ninguna librería una opción es un código como el siguiente:

```
def elementos_a_menor_que_elementos_b(a, b):
    if len(a) != len(b):
        print('Las listas no tiene el mismo tamaño')
        return False

    for item_a, item_b in zip(a, b):
        if item_a > item_b:
            return False

    return True


a = [1, 5, 5]
b = [2, 10, 8]

elementos_a_menor_que_elementos_b(a, b)
```

El operador [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip) permite iterar por cada lista, devolviendo un elemento de cada lista a la vez en cada iteración. Si prefieres no utilizar zip por encontrarlo confuso sería algo parecido a:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    item_a = a[i]
    item_b = b[i]
    [...]
```

Para obtener `1` o `0` en lugar de `True` o `False`, podrías cambiar directamente la función, "castear" a entero

```
int(True) == 1
int(False) == 0
```

Answer (score 5):

Puedes comparar directamente ambos arrays y usar `numpy.any` para ver si alguna comparación es `True` o `numpy.all` si quieres que todas sean `True`:

```
import numpy as np

c = np.all(np.array(a) < np.array(b))
```

---

```
import numpy as np

c = np.any(np.array(a) < np.array(b))
```

También puedes usar Python estándar mediante `any`/`all` y `zip`:

```
c = all(i < j for i, j in zip(a, b))
```

---

```
c = any(i < j for i, j in zip(a, b))
```

Si quieres que `c` sea 0/1 y no `True`/`False` solo debes hacer casting:

```
c = int(np.all(np.array(a) < np.array(b)))
```

Si se usa `all` retornará `True` (1) si **todos** los elementos de `a` son menores que los  correspondientes a `b`. Si se usa `any` retornará `True` si al menos un elemento lo es con respecto a su pareja.

Comment: Muy bueno. Hay una cosa que no termino de entender. ¿Por qué el argumento pasado a `any()` no es un generador o lista entre paréntesis o corchetes? Es decir, en lugar de ser `any(i < j for i, j in zip(a, b))`, que sea `any((i < j for i, j in zip(a, b)))`. Si uso la expresión pasada por argumento fuera de la llamada a `zip()` sin paréntesis o corchetes: `i < j for i, j in zip(a, b)` da un error de sintaxis. ¿Por qué dentro de la llamada a `zip()` no hace falta?

Comment: @CarlosA.Gómez solo es syntactic sugar (azúcar sintáctica). En realidad se usa un generador como dices, es equivalente a  `any((i < j for i, j in zip(a, b)))` pero te ahorras un par de paréntesis... :)

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias. Ya he comprobado que funciona igual para otras funciones que tienen también como parámetro un iterable. :)

Answer (score 3):

Puedes utilizar la función [numpy.less](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.less.html#numpy.less) para comparar las listas elemento a elemento, obteniendo así un array con valores lógicos, y luego comprobar si todos los elementos son verdaderos mediante la función [numpy.all](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html#numpy.all):

```
>>> np.all(np.less([1,5,5],[2,10,4]))
False
>>> np.all(np.less([1,5,5],[2,10,6]))
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Revisa la función `numpy.array_equal(array1, array2)`

```
import numpy as np
y=np.array_equal(array1,array2)
print(y)
```

Retora `True` si son iguales....`False` si no lo son.